# Quotes not turning out as they should while appending with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute a function via onclick, but the appended links are not containing the correct quotes and random signs are added.

```
$('#ip_list').append("<li><a onclick='setIP('" +  ip + "')'>" + ip + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right'></span></a></li>");
```

Turns out as following in Chrome Tools:

```
<a onclick="setIP(" 192.168.1.129')'="">192.168.1.129<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span></a>
```

Where does the double quote come from where i simply used single quotes around the IP-address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same type of quotes inside the `onclick` attribute as you use to delimit the attribute value, because they'll end the attribute. If you use double quotes around the attribute, use single quotes inside, and vice versa:

```
$('#ip_list').append("<li><a onclick='setIP(\"" +  ip + "\")'>" + ip + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right'></span></a></li>");
```

A better solution would be to use jQuery to bind the click handler in one place, rather than inline Javascript:

```
$("#ip_list").on("click", "li a", function() {
    setIP($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('#ip_list').append("<li><a onclick=setIP('" +  ip + "')>" + ip + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right'></span></a></li>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fh1gt4tz/

or on this way

```
$('#ip_list').append("<li><a onclick=\"setIP('" +  ip + "')\">" + ip + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right'></span></a></li>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oqt00d4z/

Comment: It's not a good idea to write attributes with no quotes around them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'` from `setIP('"` as there is a mismatch of attribute quotes `''` and quotes from the function `append("")`

```
$('#ip_list').append('<li><a onclick="setIP(\'' + ip + '\')">' + ip + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span></a></li>');
```

or as TrueBlueAussie suggested use `""` for attributes but anyways browser itself converts them.

Output:

```
<a onclick="setIP('188.87.76.21')">188.87.76.21<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span></a>
```

Comment: Your code won't work because you need quotes around the `ip` string.

Comment: @Barmar, aah Thanks. Did not think that `ip` needs to be passed as astring.

Comment: What else could it be passed as? `192.168.1.29` isn't a number.

Comment: Yes exactly. I did not think about this. I just resolved the quote mismatch. My fault!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your quotes (to mark the start and end of the attribute) are conflicting with your quotes to mark the JavaScript string literal *inside* the attribute.

The easiest way to fix this would be:

```
$('#ip_list').append("<li><a onclick=\"setIP('" +  ip + "')\">" + ip + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right'></span></a></li>");
```

... which uses `"` to mark the start and end of the attributes, and `'` to mark the JavaScript string literals. **Note** we've had to use `\` to escape the `"` used for the attributes (since that's *also* used to denote the whole string passed to `append()`). You'll find this works; http://jsfiddle.net/1yott86L/

Answer (score 0):

Weird, but it looks a bit messy with all those double and single quotes flying around.

It helps to rewrite the code to this to avoid confusion

```
$('<li>').append(
    $('<a>', { onclick: 'setIP(' +  ip + ')', text: ip})
).appendTo($('#ip_list'));
```

Much easier to read, no 'quotes within quotes' and you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

@R Lam's suggestion works as the fiddle shows.
If you really need to write the quotes around the function name like `onclick="setIP('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')"` then you should write your code like this:

```
$('#ip_list').
    append("<li><a onclick=\"setIP('" +  ip + "')\">" + ip + 
    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right'></span></a></li>");
```